# What is the equivalent of the QQQ in the UK for the FTSE 100?

Tags: stocks

I would like to know if there's an equivalent of the QQQ in the UK for the FTSE 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with QQQ, but I'm guessing this is something like IShares Ftse 100 (see description [here](http://www.stockopedia.co.uk/share-prices/ishares-ftse100-LON%3aISF/))

Answer (score 0):

I [searched for FTSE 100 fund](http://finance.search.yahoo.com/search?p=ftse+100+fund) on Yahoo Finance and found [POW FTSE RAF UK 100 (PSRU.L)](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/pr?s=psru.l), among *many* others.  Google Finance is another possible source that immediately comes to mind.

Answer (score 0):

EQQQ was launched by Nasdaq. Much closer to qqq than any etf.